# Essbase Location change using disk volume-Hyperion

Tags: hyperion, essbase

I'm looking to change the application database backup from one volume(say /v02/) to vol4 using maxl command. i tried the below commands but i could the backup artifacts under the vol4. anyone please help me..

commands i tried:
alter database application_name.Consol add disk volume '/vol4/NQITA/' ;
alter database application_name.Consol set disk volume '/vol4/NQITA/'   file_type index_data;

Comment: Have you tried changing the volume manually using EAS?

Comment: yes..i did but i want to do this via maxl command...

Comment: Gotcha. If the MaxL commands don't seem to be having the effect you want, it's possible that you need to stop/start the cube after you issue the changes, or possibly stop the cube, run the disk volume commands, then start it. I'd try that and see what happens.

Comment: i tried the same step but it is not moved..

Comment: My recollection of changing the volumes is that it won't actively move them, it'll change where future files will go. You might check the folks on the Network54 Essbase forum for some additional info.